# IE8 is doing my head in! I am getting completely different results in different versions of the same browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-browser-mode

I am developing a [site](http://novaluxenergy.com) & it all looks good on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, even IE7 but my client keeps telling me that IE8 is screwed up. I can only recreate the errors that he is getting by using IETester on my Windows 7 machine.

**My testing environment:**

I have 3 different versions of IE8 to test with & am getting completely different in the 3 versions I have to test with. I use a mac, so all tests are done on 2 virtual machines using VirtualBox - Vista with IE8 installed & Windows 7 with IE9 & IETester installed.

**Vista:**
IE8 on vista seems to run the site perfectly, albeit with a few minor bugs that I'm happy with.

**Windows 7:** Using IE9 I can change the browser & document modes, I have tried IE7, IE8 & IE9 for that matter all look totally fine. The only time I ever come close to what my client has seen is when I have used IETester - it looks almost identical to what my client has shown me from his non-IETester-using machine (by that, I have seen screengrabs of the pages he's seen).

One of the worst affected pages is the [Facts page](http://nocaluxenergy.com/facts/), there should only be one image at the top but instead I sometimes get 3! Could anyone point me in the right direction here? What is causing this random display bug on some versions of IE8 & why can I not replicate it on others.

**EXAMPLES:**

1: [Facts page](http://nocaluxenergy.com/facts/)

- How it does look (in IETester & on my client's machine): http://cl.ly/8zjY (BAD)
- How it should look: http://cl.ly/8zh7

2: [Benefits page intro](http://novaluxenergy.com/benefits/)

- How it does look (in IETester & on my client's machine): http://cl.ly/8z8X (BAD)
- How it should look: http://cl.ly/8zwz

3: [Benefits page images](http://novaluxenergy.com/benefits/)

- How it does look (in IETester & on my client's machine): http://cl.ly/8zTq (BAD)
- How it should look: http://cl.ly/8zmO

I'd like to think that I have a good handle on IE bugfixing etc but this one is really baffling me - I really need the help.

Comment: +1 - for the design, btw on my IE8 it looks great, could it be the customer is running in compatibility view ?

Comment: I think I worked out what it was. It seems that the clearfix technique I was using, I think it is the Magnificent Clearfix, used :before & :after psuedo elements to clear floats & so the background images were being applied to them. Removing the clearfix class fixed the problem. This was really strange & nearly drove me to distraction - I'm pretty sure I wasn't doing anything out of the ordinary..

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY reliable way to test a browser version is within that browser version.  The various testing applications (IETester), browser "modes" (IE7 mode in IE9, etc.), etc. **are only simulations, *each with their own unique problems***.

I too am on a Mac but I also have a real Windows machine and I use the [free VPC and hard drive images provided by MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575) specifically for this purpose.

I don't see why you couldn't run MS VPC within a Windows Virtualization on the Mac.

**EDIT:**

Essentially, you already answer your own question in your title:  *"I am getting completely different results in different versions of the same browser"*

Except the *"different versions"* are the various testing applications (IETester) and browser "modes".  Your own experience is showing you that these behave differently than the real thing.

Comment: As I said above, that is exactly what I have done. I have a 'real' version of IE8 running on Vista & IE8 using IETester on Vista & Windows 7.

Comment: @Zander:  That is **not** exactly what you have done.  IE8 within "IETester" is **not** a real version...  "IE7 or IE8 mode" within IE9 is also **not** the same as the real IE7 or IE8.... that is my point.  From what I read above, IE8 in Vista and IE9 in Win7 are the only two _real_ IE's you're using.

Comment: Correct. Using IETester is a sure way to confuse yourself. It's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Document Mode does not change the Agent string, Browser Mode does -- if you are using something like modernizr it will impact your code. You also need to check if you are running on a forced Browser Mode: IExx Compatibility View because it by defaults on Compatibility View Settings for intranet sites.