# Does IE 9 Compatibility view (IE 7 , IE 8 ) work similar to the actual browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, browser

My work deals around cross browser testing . As i cannot have different versions of Internet Explorer on the same operating system , i have different machines to facilitate the testing purpose ie.) Win 7 IE 9.0 , Win 7 IE 8.0 etc.

Note : I do not use applications like IE tester as i feel that the app cannot render an exact replication of the Browser.

Coming to the Compatibility View setting of IE 9.0 ( It simulates the page in other lower versions i.e. IE 7.0 , IE 8.0 ), would it make the Browser function exactly as the browser chosen in Compatibility view setting ?

Would it be a proper and a apt solution to having different OS instances with different IE version ? Kindly suggest .

Answer (score 2):

No, Compatibility View is not exactly the same as the browser it's trying to emulate.

See this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921057/443954

And this blog post (about IE8 but the issue is the same):
http://blogs.popart.com/2009/09/ie8-compatibility-mode-and-ie7-are-not-the-same-thing/

So you should still try to run various browser versions in your testing environment, or as a nearly-as-good alternative you might want to try out online services such as Browserling ( https://browserling.com ) or even Browsershots ( http://browsershots.org/ ).